# no sound for snap installed applications like firefox, chromium ubuntu 22.04.1 arm64 accessed with nomachine

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, snap, chromium

I am using an arm64 based ubuntu 22.04.1 oracle cloud instance, accessing it with nomachine software https://www.nomachine.com/download/download&id=113&s=ARM.

The problem is that I don't any get sound from snap installed chromium and firefox, they don't even show up in pavucontrol gui for pulse-audio.

I am getting system sound, vlc player sound and even sound from firefox installed from mozillateam repository. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04